# Ms Word 2016 Macro to Convert Text to Table One Word per Cell Regardless of Number of Words

Tags: windows, ms-word

I've recorded a macro to convert a sentence into a one-row table--one word per cell, and then do a few other things like add rows, etc.

One of the steps of the macro is to select the sentence and then convert text to table > Separate text at [space]. This works fine on the sentence I record the macro on, however, the macro stores the number of words of that sentence only, and then I cannot readily apply it to shorter or longer sentences.

Input:
`Colorless green ideas sleep furiously at night`

Output:
[image]

This is the code of the macro, which only works properly for other sentences with the same number of words. Shorter sentences > empty cells; longer sentences: stacked rows.

```
Sub Glossing()
'
' Glossing Macro
'
'
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
        NumColumns:=8, NumRows:=1, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitContent
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3
    Selection.InsertColumns
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=8, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Cells.Merge
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
    Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following VBA should do the basic job you have described, but be aware that Word tables can only contain 63 columns, so this will fail if you have more words in the selection than that.

```
Sub Glossing2()
'
' Glossing Macro
'
'
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim t As Word.Table
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
' Word creates the necessary number of columns if you omit
' the column count
Set t = Selection.ConvertToTable(Separator:=" ")
With t
  If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
    .Style = "Table Grid"
  End If
  .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
  .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
  .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
  .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
  .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
  .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False

  ' NB you have to specify a Column *object*
  ' not just a column *number*
  ' when you want to specify the "insert before" option
  .Columns.Add .Columns(1)
  .Rows.Add
  .Rows.Add
  Set r = .Range
  ' (Problem fixed by changing the second .Range.Start to .Range.End)
  r.SetRange .Cell(3, 2).Range.Start, .Cell(3, .Columns.Count).Range.End
  r.Cells.Merge
  Set r = Nothing
  .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
End With
Set t = Nothing
End Sub
```

You might need to pay a bit more attention to how the text is selected at the beginning but without knowing the precise requirement I decided not to alter what you already had.

Comment: This works perfectly. None of my sentences will be that long so it works fine. Just so I know--is .```Columns.Count``` what allows you to equate the number of columns to the word count?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's an issue with the merging of the cells in the bottom row. Ideally all the cells in the bottom row (except for the first column) must be merged; however, the right-most one doesn't merge. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Excellent. This did it!